# Failed to unpack the installation folder

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pyserial

I am trying to follow an Adafruit tutorial which requires installing pySerial. I am running mac 10.8 and run into this error when I try to unpack the installation folder. I go to the directory the file is placed and type:

```
    tar -xzf pyserial-2.6.tar.gz
```

And then the terminal prints:

```
    tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'pyserial-2.6.tar.gz'
```

I can't seem to find what I could be doing wrong, so any advice would be appreciated.

For those looking for the tutorial, the link can be found here: http://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-lesson-17-email-sending-movement-detector/installing-python-and-pyserial

Comment: Have you tried just `tar xf pyserial-2.6.tar.gz`?

Comment: Is there even a file named `pyserial-2.6.tar.gz` in the directory? Because that error from `tar` usually means you've given it a filename that doesn't exist.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: How do you expect that to help? That does the exact same thing as his command, except letting it guess at the compression instead of explicitly specifying gzip.

Comment: Also, please link to the tutorial you're following so we have some idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry if that is something very similar, I'm very new to using the terminal and didn't really know what else to try. I did, and it returned the same error. I haven't found anything on Google yet either. It's not a zip file, so unzip pyserial-2.6.tar.gz doesn't work.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, I created a directory on the desktop and when I 'ls' pyserial-2.6.tar.gz shows up. It is the only file in the directory.

Comment: I just downloaded the exact same file on a 10.8 Mac, and `tar -xzf` works if I'm in the right directory, and fails with the exact same error you see if I'm in the wrong directory. Are you sure you're actually in the right directory? (Did you type `ls` or `ls mydownloads` or something like that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't understand the terminal—or even if you do—you're going to be a lot happier using `pip` or `easy_install` than trying to do this manually. `pip` is better, but doesn't come built in with Apple's Python, so you'll have to install it first. Fortunately, that's pretty easy. So, let's do that:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

And now:

```
$ sudo pip install pyserial
```

That will automatically download, build, and install the package for you, without you having to know anything about what directory things get downloaded to or how to run the `tar` command properly or anything.

And let's test it just to make sure:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (blah blah blah … )
>>> import serial
>>> serial.VERSION
'2.6'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! It's so great as a High School programmer to have all this help from people who really know their stuff. Your help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5):

When this error occurs. It usually means that the file cannot be found. At command line of your Terminal enter "cd downloads" and search for file pyserial-2.6.tar.gz. If the file is found, proceed by entering tar -xzf pyserial-2.6.tar.gz.